# Trying to display number of Twitter followers in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter

I've been trying to get a React page to display the number of Twitter followers for an account.

Twitter will only give me key, secret and bearer token so a lot of previously written methods seem to be out of date, but even some previous answers seem not to work for me. For example I tried

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

function Twitter () {
    fetch("https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by/:username
“, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer <token>"
        }
    })
  let followerCount = user.fields.public_metrics.follower_count;
return followerCount;
}

export default Twitter;
```

In theory, this should feed the number to the next React component, but instead throws an error at the first quote mark.

At a loss as to how to achieve this now, open to trying to incorporate some npm packages but I thought it would be straightforward to display one number!

Comment: well, as syntax highlighting suggests, it's the wrong quote. Replace “ with "

Comment: Also, where is the then resolver of fetch method

Comment: @JonasWilms good spot! My code has bigger issues sadly!

Comment: @VimalPatel that's a very good question! I need to do some further research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this wont work, you have to wait till the fetch returns it response. Now it will try to fetch from api, and before the fetch returns something the function will have returned. You can use await and make the function async or use a promise.

```js
async function Twitter () {
   await fetch("https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by/:username
“, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer <token>"
        }
    })
  let followerCount = user.fields.public_metrics.follower_count;
return followerCount;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved that problem! Now I just need to work out how to handle the returned data, but that's a whole separate problem!

Comment: you could use this, or use promises, you can put the fetch in the componentdidmount in react pass it to state and get it then